# How to add time from a Date value to another without a varchar conversion?

Tags: oracle, query, datetime, date

Let's say I have 2 variables in a Stored Procedure, both are Dates

**Foo** contains `'13/10/2019 00:00:00'`

**Bar** contains `'01/10/1914 16:33:11'`

I want to add **Bar's** time to **Foo's** date, so that I get a **Foobar** variable containing `13/10/2019 16:33:11`

Is there a way to achieve this without converting any of them into a varchar?

Comment: If both are dates then Bar doesn't hold a time value.  there's no where to put it.

Comment: Do you not want to use varchar in any step or just the Foobar variable?

Comment: user1443098 - Oracle `DATE` (see tag) always contains a time component.  Other RDBMS have separate `DATE`, `TIME`, and `DATETIME` data types.  Oracle does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple addition and subtraction.

Although the code is SQL code, the math works the same in PL/SQL.

This code:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss';
with data as (
    select TO_date( '13/10/2019 00:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as foo
         , to_date( '01/10/1914 16:33:11', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as bar from dual
)
select foo, foo + (bar - trunc(bar)) foo_modified, bar from data
```

Produces this desired results:

```
FOO                 FOO_MODIFIED        BAR                
------------------- ------------------- -------------------
2019-10-13 00:00:00 2019-10-13 16:33:11 1914-10-01 16:33:11
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use DATEPART to pull the hour/min/sec from BAR and do the same to pull day/month/year from foo, them use DATEFROMPARTS to reassemble.

Pity SQL Server doesn't support the ANSI INTERVAL type, which would make this super simple.

Comment: There is no DATEPART in Oracle